# Extract Excel sheet tab colour

Tags: r, excel

We have multiple Excel files, each have multiple sheets (tabs), we want to extract tables from sheets that are coloured, for example "green".

Green sheets are not named the same way, so we can't choose based on name, and green sheets order varies between files, so we can't choose based on order.

How do we identify green sheets order?

[image]

---

#### OP is from Twitter:

https://twitter.com/FilmicAesthetic/status/1707006813122572595 :

> Outline of the problem for those interested - I'd love to hear
> solutions using any method!
>
> You have:
>
> - 30 .xlsx files
> - 20 worksheets per file (some coloured green, not uniquely named)
>
> We want:
>
> - Combine tables in just the green tabs

Answer (score 3):

Import using *openxlsx2* package, extract `sheetPr`, then extract the colours using *rvest* (or use regex):

```
library(openxlsx2)
library(rvest)

wb <- wb_load("file1.xlsx")

# extract sheetPr
x <- sapply(wb$worksheets, function(i) i$sheetPr)
x
# [1] "<sheetPr><tabColor rgb=\"FFFF0000\"/></sheetPr>"
# [2] "<sheetPr><tabColor rgb=\"FF92D050\"/></sheetPr>"

#it is an html string, read it and extract the colours
sheetCols <- sapply(wb$worksheets, function(i)
  substring(html_attr(html_node(read_html(i$sheetPr), "tabcolor"), "rgb"), 3))

sheetCols
# [1] "FF0000" "92D050"
```

[image]

```
which(sheetCols == "92D050")
# [1] 2
```

Comment: You could use
```
sapply(wb$worksheets, function(x){
  openxlsx2::xml_attr(x$sheetPr, "sheetPr", "tabColor")[[1]]["rgb"] == "92D050"
})
```

Comment: Ah well but only if all worksheets have tab color, maybe the rvest solution is moree general.

Comment: @JanMarvin Thanks, I'm not too familiar with rvest or openxlsx2, the point is, it is possible to extract the colour from "sheetPr".

Answer (score 2):

It's easy to check the tab color with VBA if OP considers VBA as an option.

```vb
Sub demo()
    Dim wk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet
    Set wk = Workbooks.Open("file1.xlsx")
    For Each sht In wk.Sheets
        If sht.Tab.Color = &H92D050 Then  '&H92D050 = 9621584
            MsgBox sht.Name
            ' your code to consolidate the data
        End If
    Next
    wk.Close False
End Sub
```

---

**Update**

> Question: can you loop through excel files and export only green sheets from those files to a new file with a single sheet?

> A sample code to search all files and merge green tab into a workbook.

```vb
Sub MergeGreenSheets()
    Dim FolderPath As String, FileName As String
    Dim wk As Workbook, MergeWk As Workbook
    Dim sht As Worksheet, MergeSht As Worksheet
    Dim LastRow As Long
    ' Set the target folder path
    FolderPath = "D:\Temp\Data\"
    ' Create a new workbook for merging data
    Set MergeWk = Workbooks.Add
    Set MergeSht = MergeWk.ActiveSheet
    ' Loop through all the xlsx files in the target folder
    FileName = Dir(FolderPath & "*.xlsx")
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Do While FileName <> ""
        Set wk = Workbooks.Open(FolderPath & FileName)
        ' Loop through all the worksheets in the current workbook
        For Each sht In wk.Sheets
            ' Check if the worksheet tab color is green
            If sht.Tab.Color = &H92D050 Then
                arrData = sht.UsedRange.Value
                MergeSht.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1).Resize(UBound(arrData), UBound(arrData, 2)).Value = arrData
                ' Copy data (with cell format) to the merging worksheet
                ' sht.UsedRange.Copy MergeSht.Cells(LastRow + 1, 1)
                ' Application.CutCopyMode = False
                LastRow = MergeSht.Cells(MergeSht.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
            End If
        Next sht
        ' Close the current workbook without saving changes
        wk.Close False
        FileName = Dir
    Loop
    ' Save the merged data to MergeData.xlsx in the D:\Data folder
    MergeWk.SaveAs FolderPath & "MergeData.xlsx"
    ' Close the merging workbook
    MergeWk.Close SaveChanges:=False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    ' Display a message indicating the merging is complete
    MsgBox "Merged file is saved to D:\Temp\Data\MergeData.xlsx"
End Sub
```

Comment: Must be an option as OP tagged Excel...

Comment: I'm not familiar with VBA, can you loop through excel files and export only green sheets from those files to a new file with a single sheet?

Comment: I came across to this problem on Twitter, I think it is fine to have VBA option, too.

Comment: Of course VBA can do it.

Comment: I have updated the code.